# Not able to query on binary field in solr

Tags: solr, solr4, solr-query-syntax

I'm not able to query on **binary** data field. I created the following field with binary field type.

```
<field name="binarycheck" type="binary" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Field type definition is the default one.

```
<fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
```

I executed the following command to index into Solr.

```
curl 'http://localhost:4983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"pd_3006","binarycheck":{"set":10101000}}]'
```

When I'm querying with the `id` field, I'm able to get the document.

[image]

Even I tried with `

> http://'localhost':4983/solr/collection1/select?q=binarycheck:10101000&wt=json&indent=true

`

But it's not giving any result. Please help

Comment: Do you want to search the binary as a whole or do you want to do bitmask style searching?

Comment: Yes. I may provide the whole binary or part of it.

Comment: Hm, answering with `yes` to an `either ... or` question is a bit hard to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Indexing of binary fields is not currently supported in Solr, only storage, which is why your query returns nothing. See cheffe's answer to a similar question here linking to a current issue tracker about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32497414/5317888

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no solution for indexing binary data.  You could change the field type to string rather than binary and still send it as Base64 encoded or as a string of raw binary, which would allow Solr to index it and allow you to query it; however, this would most likely increase the storage size for the index as a draw back.

Comment: Also similar to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845191/search-indexing-on-small-binary-fields-in-solr